# Forticlient on ARM proc (surface pro x)

Tags: arm, vpn, surface, fortigate

i can not install forticlient (last version) on microsoft surface pro x, it's rolling back & exit during the installation ..
And i tried to install & configurate SSLVPN, and when i want to connect it, it stuck at 98% and disconnect.

Please any solution to install Forticlient my surface pro x (ARM x64) ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download and install FortiClient from the Microsoft Store. It's an outdated version and appears to only support VPN functionality but it seems like the only option for ARM processors at this time.

I had that issue with a Microsoft Surface X. I tried installing:

- various versions
- restarting the pc in-between attempts
- running in different compatibility modes
- running as administrator
- disabling User Account Control
- disabling firewalls and antivirus protections
- installing Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 and 4.5.2

None them worked... when trying to install the drivers... it fails and rolled back every time. I installed the version from the Microsoft Store and that solved it.

Comment: Installing Microsoft .NET Framework and Restarting helped me. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

They are not compatible with Forti client according to Fortinet. my source I had to open a ticket with them at my company regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, until now Fortinet didn't resolve this problem on ARM processors in Windows platform. On MacOS you can install and use FortiClient on M1/2/3 processors.

There is workaround i found [here](https://community.fortinet.com/t5/FortiClient/Technical-Tip-FortiClient-for-ARM-Architecture/ta-p/248361).
To install FortiClient from Microsoft Store and then configure it from system VPN but on official webpage on release notes Fortinet said.

> Microsoft Windows-compatible computer with Intel processor or equivalent.
> FortiClient (Windows) does not support ARM-based processors.